Запятая после "что это такое" и перед "нам расскажет"
Нужна ли запятая между этими частями предложения?

Что это такое и зачем нужно нам расскажет наш собеседник.

Или:

Что это такое и зачем нужно, нам расскажет наш собеседник.


Что это такое и зачем нам  нужно —  расскажет наш собеседник.

О том, что это такое, и зачем это нужно, расскажет наш собеседник.

Тогда: О том, что это такое и зачем это нужно, расскажет наш собеседник. // Однородные придаточные.

Спасибо большое!
